# Changing repository during Use Cases/Interactors in Clean Architecture

Tags: architecture, use-case

I'm developing an Android app whose architecture is based on the well known [Uncle's Bob Clean Architecture](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).

I have the following Use Case:

**Validate User Subscription**

It's based on this use case descryption( main success scenario)

1. Check if validation warning was already shown

   - Yes -> Go to step **6**
   - No -> Go to step **2**
2. Check if user has internet connection

   - Yes -> Access remote repository
   - No -> Access local repository
3. System gets user's subscription hash in repository
4. System generates a key to decrypt the subscription hash
5. System decrypts the hash using the previously generated key and returns the status of the subscription ( *Valid* / *Invalid*)

   - Status is valid: System saves the subscription on device and changes the user type to Premium
   - Status is invalid: System saves the subscription on device changes the user type to Free
6. Use case terminates

I'm facing a problem on step 2. As you can see, I need to change my repository during the use case execution, but I don't know the best way to implement it.

*One of my ideas was to inject the repository through method injection ( using some sort of `setRepository(Repository repository`) instead of constructor injection. Is this ok?*

Comment: What do you mean by "OK?"  Note: don't answer that question with a tautology like "best practice."  *State a specific, objectively-answerable criteria.*

Comment: Well, on the majority of examples about Clean Architecture that I saw/read the use case dependencies were injected during use case construction and not execution.  Also, in my view I think that letting the use case choose the repository at execution time is bad for testing since the decision of which repository to use is inside the use case.

Comment: Why not inject a factory instead that will return the repository you need by passing it either 'local' or 'remote' as constructing arg ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question but maybe I can help others that also come looking for this answer.

I think you're confusing Repositories with DataSources.

A Repository should represent a collection of objects, or a single object, as if it were always in memory.

In your example, you would have a `UserSubscriptionRepository` with a `get()` method. This repository would have two DataSources: `RemoteUserSubscriptionDataSource` and `LocalUserSubscriptionDataSource`. Each of these would know how to get the user subscription from a different source (maybe an API for the remote and a database for the local).

Then, the `UserSubscriptionRepository` would orchestrate how and when to use each of these DataSources (change the word repository for datasource in your step 2 and this turns into the implementation of your `get()` method).

Finally, your use case would call `userSubscriptionRepository.get()` and get the data it wants, not knowing where it came from (remote or local sources).

Answer (score 1):

Try a proxy which has the remote and local repository as dependencies and use the one needed. Here is a C# implementation

```
public class ProxyRepository : IRepository

{
    private readonly IRepository _remoteRepository;
    private readonly IRepository _localRepository;

    public ProxyRepository(IRepository remoteRepository, IRepository localRepository)
    {
        _remoteRepository = remoteRepository;
        _localRepository = localRepository;
    }

    public byte[] GetUserHash(Guid userId)
    {
         if (ThereIsAnInternetConnection())
              return _remoteRepository.GetUserHash(userId);
         else
              return _localRepository.GetUserHash(userId);
    }

    private bool ThereIsAnInternetConnection()
    {
        // your implementation of this, you might want to cache this call
    }
}
```

Comment: In "clean architecture speak", this means moving the internet access check out of the Use Case and into a Gateway/Driver. This may or may not be OK, depending on if you consider "use the remote repository if there is internet access, the local repository otherwise" a business rule or not.